# Is it possible to rotate an imageview when orientation change's occur ? in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my app i want to rotate an image when orientation changes ,

in order to do this i have tried this code snippet ;

```
 public Bitmap rotateImage(String image_path){

    Log.e("Inside rotATE IMAGE", "ROTATE"+image_path);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(image_path));

    bitmap= decodeFile(image_path);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


    return  rotatedBitmap;
}

public static int getImageOrientation(String imagePath){
    int rotate = 0;
    try {

        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        Log.e("ori","or" +orientation);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}
```

This is working fine but it only checks the orientation at run time and rotates the image based on the orientation of the image ,i need to check the orientation of the device in real time and want to rotate the image to landscape mode if the device is in landscape and vice -versa.Can anyone help me please??Thank's in advance .

Comment: yes ovveride onConfigChange method and check orientation portrait or landscape and do what you want in it

Comment: is it possible to rotate an imageview when orientation change?

Comment: yes i told you logic that how you can detect that orientation of device is changed. and put your logic to rotate imageView inside that method

Comment: i am sending source plz wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void checkOrientation() {
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
            int orientation = -1;
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5) {
                    if (orientation != 1) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
                        iv.setRotation(90f);
                    }
                    orientation = 1;
                } else {
                    if (orientation != 0) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");
                        iv.setRotation(0);
                    }
                    orientation = 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply ,Thank you very much Khizar Hayat .This code works

Comment: one doubt what is value 6.5 ??

Comment: And anyway to limit the speed of rotation.??

Comment: It works with gravity so it may be some value of gravity

Comment: Hai how can i detect circular motion events using SensorManager class

Comment: I want to rotate the imagview clockwise and anti clockwise ,when the device rotated clockwise or anti clockwise

Comment: I am sorry for now i am busy right now. when have spare time will look into it.

Comment: Ok  ..Thank's for reply  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ON configuration changed u can detect like this; u will get a call back;

    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getImageOrientation();
        rotateImage();

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getImageOrientation();
        rotateImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: also in manifest mention this line if the above code is not sufficient ; for the activity mention this **android:ConfigChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"**

Comment: Thank u : I have tried this code ,but this is not working , my activity's screen orientation is already set to "Portrait" in the manifest because my app supports only portrait mode ,it's a camera application ,and i have two fragments first fragment will handle camera capture functions and sends the captured image to the second fragment ,the second fragment layout has an imageview which is used to display the image captured by the user ,so i want to rotate this fragment's imageview when orientation changes.This code will works only when i change the orientation to "fullsensor" ,

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this simple code in your activity:

 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            iv.setRotation(90f);
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            iv.setRotation(0);
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

and following line in your manifest in activity tag
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: Thank u : I have tried this code ,but this is not working , my activity's  screen orientation is already set to "Portrait" in the manifest because my  app supports only portrait mode ,it's a camera application ,and i have two fragments first fragment will handle camera capture functions and sends the captured image to the second fragment ,the second fragment layout has an imageview which is used to display the image captured by the user ,so i want to rotate this fragment's imageview when orientation changes.This code will works only when i change the orientation to "fullsensor" ,

Comment: when you restrict activity to portrait then this code ofcourse will not work

Comment: Any other way to do this in fragment ??

Comment: Yes there is a way :D happy coding :D i am sending you code